# 3D object modeling that can change whenever the option is being clicked

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, web, 3d, java-3d

I am planning to build a *website* which would show *3D model image* of a product with customization.

For *example* : I have list of furniture:

- chairs
- tables
- desk

When the button is clicked it will show the *3D image* of the item. The idea of my project is that every time the user clicks on the option given in the *left navigation*, it would promptly change the *3D image design*.

Is there a possible software to use for this? If *yes*, is that software free?

My instructor told me about *unity* and *autodesk* software, I have a no knowledge on making *3D design* but can someone humor me about this kind of stuff? Or any recommendations? hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the 3D models you can use several different programs. Autodesk could be one, blender... However if you have no idea and this is for academic purpose, you may find free 3d models.

Then to create the website you can use Unity as yous instructor say, however, not sure if it is the best approach. If you decide to continue with Unity, you can add a botton which instantiate a 3D model somewhere, for example in the center of the screen, when you click it.

I will leave you here several links you may read, and try things.

For 3D models:

- https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/
- https://www.turbosquid.com/

To work with buttons (In general to work with the UI) in Unity

- https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

To instantiate the 3D models, once you download them and you add them in your scene:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

To publish your scene as WebGL:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html

Try this things, and come back with your progress

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE TIP/INFO! <3